# GROUP BY is returning error ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: oracle, group-by

I am trying to retrieve a list of users with the highest book ID. In this example we have 3 tables, `TBL_USER`, `TBL_USER_BOOK` (bridging table) and `TBL_BOOK`. I am using the following query:

```
SELECT usr.USER_ID, MAX(sp.BOOK_ID)
FROM 
    TBL_USER usr,
    TBL_USER_BOOK ub,
    TBL_BOOK bk
WHERE usr.USER_ID = ub.USER_ID
  AND ub.BOOK_ID = bk.BOOK_ID
GROUP_BY usr.USER_ID;
```

This should return results:

```
+----------------+-------------+
|    USER_ID     |  BOOK_ID    |
+----------------+-------------+
|    1           |  23         |
|    2           |  17         |
|    3           |  32         |
+----------------+-------------+
```

But instead returns

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
>
> 933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
>
> *Cause:
>
> *Action:

If I run query

```
SELECT usr.USER_ID, sp.BOOK_ID
FROM 
    TBL_USER usr,
    TBL_USER_BOOK ub,
    TBL_BOOK bk
WHERE usr.USER_ID = ub.USER_ID
  AND ub.BOOK_ID = bk.BOOK_ID
```

it returns the correct results of

```
+----------------+-------------+
|    USER_ID     |  BOOK_ID    |
+----------------+-------------+
|    1           |  23         |
|    1           |  22         |
|    1           |  11         |
|    2           |  17         |
|    2           |   5         |
|    3           |  12         |
|    3           |   7         |
|    3           |  32         |
+----------------+-------------+
```

Why isn't my GROUP BY clause working? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `GROUP_BY` -> `GROUP  BY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by should be written without the underscore.

```
SELECT usr.USER_ID, MAX(sp.BOOK_ID)
FROM 
    TBL_USER usr,
    TBL_USER_BOOK ub,
    TBL_BOOK bk
WHERE usr.USER_ID = ub.USER_ID
  AND ub.BOOK_ID = bk.BOOK_ID
GROUP BY usr.USER_ID
```

Edit

I used SQLPLUS to run the query. It points you to the problem area.

```
SQL> SELECT usr.USER_ID, MAX(sp.BOOK_ID)
  2  FROM
  3      TBL_USER usr,
  4      TBL_USER_BOOK ub,
  5      TBL_BOOK bk
  6  WHERE usr.USER_ID = ub.USER_ID
  7    AND ub.BOOK_ID = bk.BOOK_ID
  8  GROUP_BY usr.USER_ID;
GROUP_BY usr.USER_ID
*
ERROR at line 8:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Comment: Oh my god... Thank you! Sometimes you just need a second set of eyes to look over your code :)

Comment: Some of the tools can help you. Even simple sqlplus. See my edit.

Comment: Ah okay - I am running in SQL Developer which doesn't give me any useful output.

Comment: I have another tool but it surprises me that SQL Developer leaves you in the dark.

Comment: time to update to TOAD I think haha

Comment: Just tried it in SQLDeveloper. This is what I get:

ORA-00933: SQL-opdracht is niet juist beëindigd.
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 8 Column: 1